# Array issues: Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, runtime-error

I'm in the middle of writing a function that requests an array, and if it finds a capital letter, it is supposed to swap the entire row into the captial letter. otherwise, it just prints the function.
Running the main function up to the part where the function is checking for captial letters is okay, and I get the error mentioned in the title.

main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FuncA.h"
#include "printarr.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "Welcome, choose a function to continue: " << endl << "\n A for Uppercasing arrays. \n B for Column sum. \n C for String copying. \n D for exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)


            case 'A':
                    funca();

        } 
        while (choice != 'D');

    }
```

And the function in question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FuncA.h"
#include "printarr.h"
using namespace std;

void funca()
{
    int  rows = 0, cols = 0; //init
    cout << "how many rows? ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "\n how many cols? ";
    cin >> cols;
    char arr[][COLS] = {0};


    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) // input
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < cols; i2++) // capcheck and printing if caps not detected
    {
        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < rows; j2++)
        {
            if (arr[i2][j2] >= 90 || arr[i2][j2] <= 65)
            {
                printarr(arr, rows, cols);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

How do I fix this issue? I tried changing the size of COLS (the size is defined in the .h file) but that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration of `arr` is equal to `char arr[1][COLS]`. Any non-zero index for the first "dimension" will be out of bounds.

If you want an "array" with a size set at runtime then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> arr(cols, std::vector<char>(rows));
```

Comment: Also, there is no check at all that `cols` would be less or equal than `COLS`.